# Gwibber window is blank

Tags: gwibber

I'm now using **Gwibber** as my social
Empathy is work correctly with my facebook google account

I want to use Gwibber to send/receive my email
**but when i open appear but inside show nothing, only blank**,
click the icon but nothing shown

*Sorry i can't use the image yet (low reputation.......)*

my problem

1. i want to use gwibber as my mail system
2. facebook and google chat can work correctly in empathy

[image]

Comment: Gwibber is *not* a mail application, Evolution, Thunderbird or Claws Mail are.

Comment: here i upload my screenshot about gwibber

Comment: Many users have a same problem,it's maybe a bug and you can follow it from here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1058672
Do some search before create new question.